# What is the difference between element and selector?

Tags: jquery

I think that the selector is the HTML tag you use to reference a portion of HTML code such as:

```
$('.class_one')
```

And I think that the element are the contents of the selector.

Is this correct?

Comment: A selector is the string you pass in to the `$()` function to get the collection of elements back

Answer (score 0):

Elements are blocks on page and you are selecting them by selectors.

Answer (score 0):

[An Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) is an actual reference to the Element in the DOM. A Selector is a String that is defined by, in this case, jQuery , as a rule to select certain Elements.